# How to fix okHttp3 cause Source code does not match the Bytecode

Tags: kotlin, okhttp

Im using the following:

1) Android studio v3.5.3

2) use this dependencies:

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'

Problem:

I debug with a physical android phone.
When I did run on debug mode,it would show Source code does not match the Bytecode when entering the http request.   after 30 second or more, then the photo showed up. It should not take so long.

I did the following:
1) Clean the build and rebuild. But it does not work and it still show the same message.

How to solve this issue.  please help. Thanks

```
fun getImage(strImgURL: String){

    val url = "https://xxx" + strImgURL.trim()

    val okrequest = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val okclient = OkHttpClient()


        okclient.newCall(okrequest).enqueue(object : Callback {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {

                e?.printStackTrace()
                runOnUiThread {
                    tvStatus.setText("")                     
                }
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {

                val inputStream = response?.body()?.byteStream()
                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)

                 if (bitmap != null) {

                     runOnUiThread {
                     tvLoc.text = strDBCheckName
                     tvStatus.setText("")
                     tvTime.text = "Time " + strTime
                     ImgVw.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                     }

                 } else {

                     runOnUiThread {
                         tvStatus.setText("")

                     }
                 }
            }
        })


}
```

Comment: Can you clearify your problem? Does the request just need to long or does it give you a wrong result?

Comment: @J.Gerbershagen  yes, it took too long to show the image. When I used the Debug Mode ( the one with Bug icon), it show the Source Code does not match the Bytecode when entering the OkHttp Request process. What cause it and why it still able to get result and didnot crash. Does it make a difference when OkHttp deal with Http and HttpS ?